# Difference between querySelector() and querySelectorAll()[0]

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I ran across some JS code using the following to select the first of multiple nodes.

```
querySelectorAll()[0]
```

Isn't the following doing the exact same thing?

```
querySelector()
```

Is there an advantage of using `querySelectorAll()[0]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both expressions will return the exact same result.

The only difference is the `querySelectorAll()[0]` will first find all the items that match the selector and then index the first item. Whereas `querySelector()` will "short circuit" once it finds the first element.

So, theoretically, `querySelector()` might be marginally more efficient than `querySelectorAll()[0]`. However, their behaviour is identical.

Comment: *"They do the exact same thing."* and then you go on to describe how the do very different things.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm saying the two methods return the exact same value. I'll clarify in my answer.

Comment: I knew that's what you meant, but that wasn't what you said. ;)

Answer (score 1):

They both result in the same thing, but they take different routes (literally and figuratively) to get there. In your example, `.querySelector()` is the correct approach because `.querySelectorAll()` will incur more of a performance hit by scanning the entire element that the method is called on when it only needs to use the first match.

The advantage to `.querySelectorAll()` is that you can cache a reference to the entire set of matched elements and then index them or loop them as needed later. So, if there was a need for the first matched element, but the entire set was going to be needed somewhere else in the code, then `.querySelectorAll(<<selector>>)[0]` would make sense.